# While calling SAP hybris service facing issue in SAP CAI chatbot

Tags: openssl, chatbot, sap-commerce-cloud, sap-conversational-ai

I have created my own chatbot using SAP Conversational AI and I have integrated it with the SAP hybris 1905 storefront and it's working fine.
But when I am trying to call SAP hybris backend service from SAP conversation AI to fetch the data it's showing the below error.

```
PKIX path building failed: Details: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is Details: PKIX path building failed: Details: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

To resolve this issue I have installed a self-signed SSL certificate.
But I'm still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that can be seen from your explanations.

The issue you are seeing from this error message shows, that the installed certificate (or more precise: the certificate information provided by your server) does not contain the full certificate chain, which makes the SSL certificate validation fail.

For further explanation there is also an example available on badssl.com, which shows various error sources in the SSL certificate configuration:
https://incomplete-chain.badssl.com/

A similar question was already asked and answered on the [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12921475/sap-cai-webhook.html)

Even if you would fix the incomplete chain of your certificate I won't work probably, as you have installed a self-signed certificate (based on your description). Self-signed certificates are not trusted by SAP Conversational AI, as they would be a severe security issue within a cloud product. There are some further explanations on self-signed certificates not trusted by SAP Conversational AI available [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13055132/can-we-bypass-self-signed-https-calls-in-cai-consu.html?childToView=13058128#answer-13058128)